# I don't underestand template_name_field?

Tags: python, django, django-views

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = None
    template_name_field = None
```

1. Why `template_name_field` default value is None?
2. `template_name_field` default value will be `'article_detail.html'`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why `template_name_field` default value is `None`?

The [**`template_name_field=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin.template_name_field) specifies the name of an attribute of the object to look for when determining the template. In case it is `None`, Django will not look for such attribute. You however do *not* need to specify `template_name_field=None`: this is already the case due to inheritance, so the `template_name_field = None` line is not neccesary.

> 2. `template_name_field` default value will be `'article_detail.html'`

**No**, you can use the [**`template_name=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.template_name) to specify the name of the template. The `template_name_field` specifies the name of an *attribute* of the object that specifies the name of the template. In other words, you could have a model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    template_to_render = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

where you thus have for example a field that contains the *name* of the template to render, then you can set `template_name_field='template_to_render'`. Django will thus then for that object look for that attribute, and in case such attribute exists use that as the name of the template to render.

In case both `template_name` and `template_name_field` are `None`, Django will make a final fallback and look for the name of the model (here likely `Article`), and will try to render a template named `app_name/modelnamesuffix.html` with *`app_name`* the name of the app where you defined the model, *`modelname`* the name of the model in lowercase (so here `article`), and *`suffix`* the value for the [**`template_name_suffix=…`** attribute <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin), which is by default `'_detail'`, so it will look for a template named `app_name/article_detail.html` with *`app_name`* the name of the app where you defined the `Article` model.